# trouble using lambda expressions and auto keyword in c++

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, mingw, auto

I'm trying to learn how to use lambda expressions in C++.

I tried this simple bit of code but I get compile errors:

```
int main()
{   
    vector<int> vec;
    for(int i = 1; i<10; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),[](int n){cout << n << " ";});
    cout << endl;
}
```

Errors:

```
    forEachTests.cpp:20:61: error: no matching function for call to'for_each(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, main()::<lambda(int)>)'

    forEachTests.cpp:20:61: note: candidate is:
    c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:4373:5: note:template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct)
```

I also tried making the lambda expression an auto variable but I got a different set of errors.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{   
    vector<int> vec;
    for(int i = 1; i<10; i++)
    {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    auto print = [](int n){cout << n << " ";};
    for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),print);
    cout << endl;
}
```

This gave me the following errors:

```
    forEachTests.cpp: In function 'int main()':

    forEachTests.cpp:20:7: error: 'print' does not name a type

    forEachTests.cpp:22:33: error: 'print' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm assuming these are problems with my compiler but I am not quite sure.
I just installed MinGW and it appears to be using `gcc` 4.6.2.

Comment: This might have something to do with your compiler.  This compiles just fine in ideone: http://ideone.com/gcQEG

Comment: Did you specify the `-std` flag when you compile?

Comment: okay now auto seemed to work with -std=c++0x.  when i compiled it was giving me a warning to use that but also said it was enabled by default.  I guess it lied about the default.  I'll see if the first example code works now

Comment: nice, that one works too.  Guess I shouldn't always believe something when it tells me it's enabled by default.  If you want to add that as the answer so I can accept it go ahead.  Otherwise i'll add the answer myself.

Comment: @AndyEntrekin, It took me a while to figure out, but it means the warning is enabled by default (i.e. you don't need any compile options to spew it out). Also, the option `-std=c++11` works too.

Comment: `-std=c++11` instead of `-std=c++0x` appears to be working only in GCC 4.7.0 and higher. Also the documentation ([4.6.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc.pdf) and [4.7.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.0/gcc.pdf)) suggests this, see page 7.

Comment: GCC 4.6.2 is old, upgrade if you want to use C++11.

Answer (score 8):

You have to specify the standard option `-std=c++0x` (for gcc prior to version 4.7.0) or `-std=c++11` (for gcc version 4.7.0 and later) when compiling the code under the new C++11 standard.

Comment: If you find this post outdated, please ping me with the correct information or submit an edit to this post. I can't keep track of and maintain all thousand of post that I currently have. Thanks.

Comment: @corporatewhore "y" is not "the current year", C++1y was the "codename" for C++14 before it was finished, just like C++0x was the name for C++11 (and C++1z is the name for C++17). And you should update your GCC, as of at least a year ago that error message says "-std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14" instead. But that error is for a different piece of code not the one in the question above, your edit doesn't improve this answer.